# cakephp access to input not on model data array

Tags: javascript, cakephp, input

To process a string on my view, I've added an input the user fills with text. (no server or uploads involved). This input does no correspond to any data field.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('fullPathInput', array('label' => 'Copied Path', 'id' => 'fullPath' , 'onchange' => "assignPath();")); ?>
```

I need to check that this input is not empty. How do I access the input? 
As expected, it's not on the

```
$this->data['Model']['field'];
```

array.

Printed

```
print_r($this->request->data);
```

and is nowhere.

I've been able to access it via JavaScript, for another purpose, but I'd like to do this:

```
$thevalue = $this->data['myInputName'];
if (empty($thevalue)) {
    --actions--
} else {
    -- actions --
}
```

Can you help on how to access that input?  ...A simple JavaScript function can tell me if my input is empty or not, but then I'd need the Boolean from js to be used on the condition a few lines above. Do you know how I'd do that?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you asking how to check the value in the Controller?

Comment: hi Dave, No, in the same view. I've been able to get data this way via `$origDate2 = $this->data['Nodata']['date2'];` but this time my input is not part of the data array.

Comment: Just use DebugKit and view all the data being passed to the page.  (DebugKit is literally a MUST-HAVE for any/every CakePHP project - not exaggerating)

Comment: little hint: check your posted code to consistency of mentioned index, name, etc. if people - like me, for example ;) - get confused, because of the naming it gets harder and harder to give a good answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ModelName.fullPathInput', array('label' => 'Copied Path', 'id' => 'fullPath' , 'value' => $thevalue, 'onchange' => "assignPath();")); ?>
```

`$thevalue` is the variable that hold the value of input at the initial level before calling your javascript assignPath() function.

Comment: Kindly ask if it not worked for you. One more thing that, `onChange` is an event for the select box, but your form input didn't seems to be selectbox.

Comment: Hi Arun, Thank you for the tip. It did not work as `'ModelName.fullPathInput`, still can't access the input and is not part of data array. As for the `$value` variable, it is only intended to get the input value at a later time, such as `$thevalue = $this->data['myInputName'];
`. The `onchange` event is also for text inputs and is working just fine. The problem is how to access the input value.

Comment: The common reason might you have not written the `fullPathInput` field into the form. Check whether this input field is with in the form or outside the form.